# Receiving error when trying to login to APEX App with Windows Credentials - LDAP

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I'm trying to set up an Authentication Scheme for users to use their System Login, using LDAP.

These are the settings:

```
LDAP HOST = Required IP Entered
PORT = Required Port Entered
USE SSL = No SSL
Distinguished Name = Enabled
Distinguished Name String = cn=%LDAP_USERS%,OU=<My Org name>, DC=,My Org Domain>,DC=com
```

When I try to Test Login I am getting this error:

```
ORA-31204: DBMS_LDAP: PL/SQL - Invalid LDAP Session.
```

I found a fix for this online:

```
DECLARE
    l_ldap_host VARCHAR2(100) := 'My IP';
    l_ldap_port NUMBER := 8080;
    l_ldap_user VARCHAR2(100) := 'cn=%LDAP_USER%,OU=My ORG,DC=My Domain,DC=com';
    l_ldap_password VARCHAR(100) :='Trayobean199528*';
    l_session RAW(32);
    l_retval NUMBER;

BEGIN

l_session := (hostname => l_ldap_host,
            portnum => l_ldap_port);
            
l_retval := DBMS_LDAP.simple_bing_s(id => l_session,
                                dn => l_ldap_user,
                                password => l_ldap_password);

dbms_output.put_line(l_retval);


END;
```

and I received this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 11, column 15:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 11, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 14, column 23:
PLS-00302: component 'SIMPLE_BING_S' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 14, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

What can be done to rectify this? I'm using Oracle SQLDeveloper and Apex v22

Comment: Error is pretty self-explanatory. When trying to compile - that is when you got this error - the database cannot resolve the component "SIMPLE_BING_S"... because it doesn't exist. You want SIMPLE_BIND_S - with a D not a G...

Comment: Hey @KoenLostrie I made the change (honestly didn't notice that as the code was given to me) but sqldeveloper is saying "simple_bind_s has to wrong number or types of arguments."

Comment: Check the docs before posting any answer please. I'm not at all a specialist in this, you'll have to figure this out mostly yourself. The docs will show you what the signature of the procedure SIMPLE_BIND_S  is. If you spell the names wrong it won't work and throw the error you're seeing...